# Couldn't get value from input field in jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have this input filed whose name and id is phone and I have to get value from this input field using ajax but couldn't get it. It just give me empty value and there is no any error too in console.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaKXt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbQEX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U01C.png)

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Error in the first line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbQEX.png)

It should be

```
$(document).on('click','.send-otp-button',function(e){
```

Comment: Actually I make variable first of all like this:
 var $loginBox = $('.login-box');
so I call function like:
 $loginBox.on('click', '.send-otp-btn', function (e) {
}
And another thing is there is no any class called "send-otp-button", I sure there is class called "send-otp-btn"